# File descriptor table - parent/child sharing it

Tags: c, unix, posix

I am trying to create an example (to aid my understanding of the following concept):

A child process inherits its parent’s open files.
which can be seen in this diagram http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~rich/class/cs170/notes/FileSystem/filetable.rich.jpg

this is my code:

```
 FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

 if(fork()==0){

    printf("%c",  fgetc(f) ); //should print e
    printf("%c",  fgetc(f) ); //should print s
    printf("%c",  fgetc(f) ); //should print t
    printf("\n");
 } else {
    printf("%c",  fgetc(f) ); // print t

 }
```

test.txt containts the words `test`.

assuming the parent runs firsts, if the parent and child have the same descriptor table, shouldn't the system output `t(from parent)est(from children)`. currently the output is `t▒▒▒▒`.

thanks
daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C stdio library uses buffering for efficiency. Even though you are reading only one character, the `fgetc` function reads an entire buffer from the file. For such a small file this means that the process that is scheduled first reads it entirely.

You can disable buffering with a call to `setvbuf`. Alternatively you could use functions that operate on file descriptors directly (`open`, `read`).